# Appending a checkbox inside a <td> returns [object, Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a small project working on. When I add items to my array they will display in a table below my fields.

My problem is that when I try to append a checkbox it returns `[object, Object]`.

My HTML:

```html
<div class="container">
    <input id="list-input" />
    <select id="select-status">
        <option value="on-going">on-going</option>
        <option value="completed">completed</option>
    </select>
    <button id="add">Add To List</button>
    <button id="delete">Remove From List</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <h1>Your List</h1>

    <div id="mylist">
        <table id="mylist">
            <thead>
                <th>ID Number</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button id="clear">clear</button>
</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```js
var tasks = [];
var count = 0;

$('document').ready(function(){

    $('#add').click(function() {
        var desc    = $.trim($('#list-input').val());
        var status  = $('#select-status option:selected').val();
        var id      = Date.now();
        item        = {};

        if (!desc) {
            item.id = "";
            alert("Input a description");
            return;
        }

        item.id          = id;
        item.description = desc;
        item.status      = status;
        tasks.push(item);

        var tr  = "<tr>";
        var td1 = "<td id="+ item.id +">" + item.id + "</td>";
        var td2 = "<td>" + item.description + "</td>";
        var td3 = "<td>" + item.status + "</td>";
        var td4 = "<td>" + $('<input/>',{'type':'checkbox'}) + "</td>" ;

        $("#mylist tbody").append(tr + td1 + td2 + td3 + td4);

        //clear input field
        $('#list-input').val('');
    });

    //clear list function
    $('#clear').click(function(){
        tasks = [];

        $('#mylist tbody').empty();

        setTimeout(function(){
            alert("List is now empty!");
        }, 500);

    });

    //remove list function

    $('#delete').on('click', function() {
      $('#mylist input:checked').closest('#item').remove();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
var td4 = "<td>" + $('<input/>',{'type':'checkbox'}) + "</td>" ;
```

creates a jQuery object and then concatenates it with a string. Most objects don't implement `toString` (and jQuery objects don't), so you get the default `"[object Object]"` string.

You're already working in markup, keep doing that:

```
var td4 = "<td><input type='checkbox'></td>" ;
```

...or switch over the code to working with objects instead.